# iReport: getting "Incompatible java.math.BigDecimal value assigned to parameter" exception

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am developing report containing sub report using `iReport` and i am passing two external parameters in master report: the `CurrWeek` and `CurrYear` parameters. I'm passing the same parameters to the subreport.

In both reports I declared parameters as `BigDecimal`. When i run the report it shows the error shown bellow:

```
   Error filling print...
        net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException:
     Incompatible java.math.BigDecimal value assigned to parameter 
    CurrWeek in the WeeklyReportForOtherWeek dataset. 
     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: 
     net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: 
     Incompatible java.math.BigDecimal value assigned to parameter 
     CurrWeek in the WeeklyReportForOtherWeek dataset.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error mean that you pass wrong type from dataset to parameter.

Look at the place where you are creating (filling) dataset.